# Why is Landau-Zener formula only available for two-level system, but unable to be extended to higher level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Landau-Zener formula only applies to closed two-level system. Although similar ideas have been applied to three levels ([example](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/19/11/014)), they are restricted to special cases like the atom being driven by laser beams.

What is the difficulty in having an analytical formula like Landau-Zener formula for closed $N$-level systems? Will one be able to derive such formula?

Comment: It's not restricted to two level systems. It's just an approximation that very close to level crossing all the other possible transitions are negligible (due to high energy gap) and you should diagonalize only the relevant $2 \times 2$ matrix. With more than 2 levels is just the same algorithm, and there is some literature about it.